# PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY failed while sending signed SAMLRequest to Auth0

Tags: .net-core, certificate, auth0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm trying to sign the (ITfoxtec Identity SAML2) SAMLRequests and testing with Auth0 and I'm getting the following error on the Auth0 side:

> invalid_request: PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY failed

I filled the public key in their config.

```
{
  "signatureAlgorithm": "rsa-sha256",
  "digestAlgorithm": "sha256",
  "signingCert": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAqt7eddg/N9MgaivTEWif\n...\nnmEbAFKJtjieiwu1JjsMsdUCAwEAAQ==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
}
```

Here is how I generated the keys:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout auth0samlprivate.key -out auth0samlpublic.pem -days 3650 -nodes -subj "/CN=mydomain.com"

# then i generate the public key to fill in the configuration of Auth0
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in auth0samlpublic.pem  > auth0samlpublickey.pem

# then I generate the .pfx file to use server side for the private key
openssl pkcs12 -export -out auth0saml.pfx -inkey auth0samlprivate.key -in auth0samlpublic.cer
```

Then in the code:

```
config.SignAuthnRequest = true;
config.SigningCertificate = CertificateUtil.Load("Path/To/auth0saml.pfx", "myPassword");
```

In the browser, I get redirected to the right URL that contains a Signature query parameter, so it seems to be handled correctly but Auth0 doesn't seem to be able to read it.

What did I miss? I'm new to the certificate part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was about the generated certificate.

First, although the example in Auth0 is using a private key, using certificate is fine too.

The following commands worked fine for me:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout auth0samlprivate.pem -out auth0samlpublic.pem -days 3650 -nodes -subj "/CN=thefiftyapp.com"

openssl pkcs12 -export -in auth0samlpublic.pem -inkey auth0samlprivate.pem -out auth0saml.pfx
```

I think the real issue was about changing manually the pem file to a cer file without using a command line.

And the Auth0 config:

```
{
  "signatureAlgorithm": "rsa-sha256",
  "digestAlgorithm": "sha256",
  "signingCert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDFTCCAf2gAwIBAgIUXg1jHZ9qRIrtySCsF/bK2JvYxMQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\n...\n53f63eKJn9PMmyqIYl9/K48ABR3Bf8exfvK4HRudkSU66pQsj8biIxl4MSDMg/6G\naHUZoTBJbJ/sXmoExGpltvFDcNMITfJMKGFCIBO9VnlsJrXdwalSTpxg/9Yi79GD\n5yMXEjicqion8KE0LMsk93LVS92bkujhSg==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
}
```